# Location is set by GPS although GPS is supposed to be disabled

Tags: android

I am using the following code for getting the location:

```
localCriteria = new Criteria();
              localCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
              localCriteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
              localCriteria.setBearingRequired(false);
              localCriteria.setCostAllowed(true);
              localCriteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
              localCriteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
              mProvider = mLocMan.getBestProvider(localCriteria, true);
 mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 0, 0f, this);
```

Although my phone settings is set to Medium Accuracy ( meaning network and wifi, no gps), but when I run the application, it displays the GPS icon on the on the notification bar with the location  being set by GPS!!

Shouldn't the GPS be disabled and no location acquired as a result? I am not sure what is happening

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is not only used for GPS-locating but for all location-acquiring. [Setting the location settings](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-change-your-location-settings-android) to 'medium'/ power saving means that GPS isn't used to acquire the location, but wifi and mobile network cells are. The phone can still locate itself, thus the icon appears. 
I don't even know though how to completely disable any location services on Android 5.0.

You can [check for yourself](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider%28%29) what Provider (source of locattion) was used when receiving the Location. If the Provider IS Gps, this might be an actual bug in your firmware / Android version.

Comment: I don't think this is very true. The reason is, when I open google map, it does not show this icon. Also, if  I replace the above code with the new location API (FusedLocation) then the GPS icon does not appear. I have android version 4.4

Comment: See edit, check for yourself which provider was used.

Comment: Yea it is GPS.. Hmm I have S4 phone. So you think it is bug in firmware? Not android

Comment: Your specific firmware build must have been made with changes to that code.(GPS stuff). This makes sense because your OEM wanted to make apps compatible even when an app requires GPS Provider and does not receive it. (In case of location services being disabled, GPS that is, fallback to Mobile and wifi triangulation) This is the best answer i can think about. <b>Suggestion is try your code with a nexus device</b> Nexus devices are stock. 0 code modifications. Best to develop apps.